# How to dynamically add multiple Contents to an expander in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, expander

I have a method that adds multiple expanders in wpf, from the input of a combobox. After the combobox item is selected, a OpenFileDialog opens, and gets a filename.  This happens more than once, and I seem to be overwriting my Content for the expander.  Code below

```
private void comboBox_SetFileNames(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = combobox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
    if (selectedItem != null)
        string name = selectedItem.Name;
        Expander expander = new Expander {Header = name};

        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
        dlg.Filter = "Text File (*.txt) | *.txt";
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            expander.Content = new TextBlock() { Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dlg.FileName) };
        }

        dlg.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx) | *.xlsx";
        Nullable<bool> result2 = dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (result2 == true)
        {
            expander.Content = new TextBlock() { Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dlg.FileName) };
        }
        dock.Children.Add(expander);
    }
}
```

Any way to have each of these file names listed below one another? so something like below

```
ExpanderName
|
------FileName1.txt
|
------FileName2.xlsx
```

Right now with it getting overwritten it looks like this:

```
ExpanderName
|
------FileName2.xlsx
```

Comment: Set your `expander.Content` to a `StackPanel`, and add your `TextBlocks` to the `StackPanel`. The `Content` property can only be set to a single value, while a StackPanel can contain multiple controls.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  If you'd like to put that as an answer, and give a small example if you'd like, I'll accept it as an answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your `expander.Content` to a panel like a `StackPanel`, and add your `TextBlocks` to it instead.

The `Content` property can only be set to a single value, while a panel like the `StackPanel` can contain multiple controls.

Something like this:

```
Expander expander = new Expander {Header = name};
StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();

var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
dlg.Filter = "Text File (*.txt) | *.txt";
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

if (result == true)
    panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = dlg.SafeFileName });

dlg.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx) | *.xlsx";
Nullable<bool> result2 = dlg.ShowDialog();

if (result2 == true)
    panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = dlg.SafeFileName });

expander.Content = panel;
dock.Children.Add(expander);
```